# Mobile stylesheet not working - wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, mobile

I've just gone from making a website go from pure html into wordpress, for some reason now it is in wordpress the mobile stylesheet and javascript is not applying?

Any ideas? Really flumoxed, it worked before when done in pure html, does something in wordpress interfear?

Link: http://dev.empa-photography.co.uk

Comment: This is extremely hard to answer. Wordpress is a backend technology. It won't affect how your frontend code works. However, in the transformation of your website from HTML template into Wordpress template a lot of things could have gone wrong. Look at the output very closely and see if it really looks exactly the same as in your HTML template. Sounds like you're missing a file or so.

Comment: Weirdly, it works if I drag the window on my computer and refresh just not on actual mobiles?

Comment: It's not weird. If you would have put that in your question, and said that you had a responsive design, this would have been solved ages ago. Posted something for you to try now here below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Amongst your other meta attributes. This tells the device to show the website with the same width as the device's width. Your problem right now is that the device's browser is saying my width is [some desktop-sized value] so the responsive part doesn't come into play because it only kicks in for smaller widths.